# "The type or namespace name 'Devices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure"

Tags: azure

I am a newbie to c# script language. I am using C# script for connecting Azure function to IoT central. So that I can send telemetry data to IoT Central. Doing it from Azure portal itself. And getting an error like

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Devices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

This error is with the package `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client`.

That is, getting the error in the line `using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;`

I have added the function.proj file also for adding the nuget package in the azure function. .And tried with different versions of this nuget package. Still i am getting the same error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance